# Dotnetnuke development to production migration

Tags: dotnetnuke, web-deployment, packaging, dotnetnuke-7

I have currently updated our DNN site to version 7.4.2.

I have implemented skin & content changes for our site in local environment and want to know the best path to deploy these changes to our production site.

I have tried using the Export site template option. Although while importing it, a new portal is created. I don't want to create new portal. My changes include html/text content changes, ListX changes and Skin changes.

Is there any way I can deploy these changes as a single package to our existing site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNN doesn't support a good way to do this. Typically people will do it manually, reapplying all the changes themselves in the production environment.